# Best way to create custom html joomla link

Tags: javascript, html, module, joomla

I'm new to Joomla , just want to understanding the best way to implement this.

[http://jsfiddle.net/*PSYCKIC*/JyKJf/](http://jsfiddle.net/_PSYCKIC_/JyKJf/)

The **IDEA** is to use that as a link , i click there and lead me to a article or link. (didn't include the javascript in the example)

**PROBLEMS** : 
-I was doing as a custom HTML, but the problem probably have to use javascript for the link but when i save it save without javascript (and probably it a little hardcoded)
-  doesnt work for div

**LOOKING** the best way:

1) Have some ideas , one was to create a module, or something where i just put the image , link of the article and then is always automatically ( but not sure how to import javascript/jquery trough modules ANY HELP? Someone can help me building?)

2) any good module already created for this?

3) Tutorial than can help me understand?

Like a solution where i have possibility to reuse the code not hardcoded.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: implement it directly to the template and maybe usw the extension form2content

Comment: Can someone help me to create a mod to create that element where i can choose a image and add a new link?

Answer (score 0):

There are some Joomla extentions which allow to insert into joomla site any code

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-modules/8651
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-modules/2861

If you want to include such code into article, you have to publish module in any position and then use this shotrcode {loadposition _any_position_}.

I hope it will be helpfull

Comment: Thanks but that seems the same as the editor, create the code and paste. Not give me a lot of flexibility for users to change photos and link. Probably a better solution is create my own mod or plugin.

Comment: Sure, you could create your own plugin. It was my second idea :)

Comment: Any code already start for that? at leat including two fields an image(you select from the joomla media) and a link url (select a article or something else)

Comment: I think, the best way would be to create plugin which could parse article text and found/replace shortcode like this {link img=path/to/img url=www/site/com/ /} with needed code.

Comment: Uhm..better a plugin than a mod? Will look on that, thanks. Any example how to do it?

Comment: Modules aren't used for these purposes. Module's mission is displaying small part of any information. But you need to change article text on fly. http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla_1.5 - official documentation. You should handle this event http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin_events/Content#onPrepareContent. For example you could check default Joomla plugin `\plugins\content\loadmodule.php`. This plugin searchs in article text {loadposition _position_} and loads all modules published into _position_. Its code pretty simle.

Answer (score 0):

Which Joomla Version are you using?
You have to disable the built in filtering of joomla and your editor:

http://www.tutorials2learn.com/2010/02/cms/fix-tinymce-editor-strips-flash-embed-code-joomla/

for your eitor, go to plugins -> editor -> options -> filter onload ...

you dont need an extra extension for just a simple javascript link

Comment: Using Joomla 1.7 , probably will work... but still seems a bad idea if i like to use the same code several times . Sao a normal user can easily add.

Comment: You mean you want to use it as html module? That works if you disable the global filters of jommla as i wrote. Dont know what you mean exactly by using the same code multiple times. then why not include the javascript file directly into the template?

Comment: Thanks by the way for the reply.

Comment: That is another options to create in the template. But i would like a future user can use the module to create several like the example.

Comment: But using at same time other images, resize and change the link without going to the code. For normal users they do not understand. If possible a module or plugin that does that.